# US Outbound Passenger List information

Tags: united-states, immigration, italy

Is there a listing of outbound ship passengers leaving New York City ports during the early 1900s to Europe (Italy)?

My mother, born in the Bronx, New York City in 1907 was taken to Italy to live by her parents. I do not know exactly when bit it may have been 1912. She did not immigrate back to the US until 1953. I have her inbound passenger info, but not her outbound. I'm researching in trying to understand the citizenship status of her minor children who came to the US in 1954. US Citizen by Derivation Laws are confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The US did not require keeping lists of outbound passengers during this period (1907ish), so you won't find outbound passenger lists for New York City  comparable to the incoming Ellis Island lists. There are records about outbound ships after 1917, but they are registers of departing vessels and pertain to the ships. They don't contain lists of passengers. Most of the departure lists filmed by NARA are from 1957 and afterwards.

However, you might be able to find mentions of her family going back to Italy in other sources such as historical newspapers, Customs Lists, or records of
immigrant aid societies.

If you haven't already, assemble the information you know with a note of where the information came from.

- Build a timeline for your mother and for other close family members
- Make a list of all the variant spellings, bad transcriptions, and OCR errors associated with your family members

If you need help with dual citizenship, I highly recommend hiring a professonal that specializes in Italy and will already be familiar with the laws concerning derivative citizenship in the US and Italian citizenship requirements.

Resources:

- [Passenger Arrival Records at the National Archives](https://historyhub.history.gov/genealogy/immigration-and-naturalization-records/b/immigration-naturalization-blog/posts/passenger-arrival-records-at-the-national-archives) Overview by Elizabeth Burnes at NARA's History Hub
- an answer to the question [Departing Passenger Ships and Passports from USA](https://historyhub.history.gov/genealogy/immigration-and-naturalization-records/f/discussions/27092/departing-passenger-ships-and-passports-from-usa) by Elizabeth Burnes on NARA's History Hub
- an answer to the question [Seeking departure manifests for the early 1900s](https://historyhub.history.gov/thread/15549) by Lisa Penn on NARA's History Hub
- Extra information page for Ancestry's database [U.S., Departing Passenger and Crew Lists, 1914-1966](https://search.ancestry.com/search/dbextra.aspx?dbid=60882), listing NARA microfilms contained in the collections.
- NARA: Passenger Lists - [Browse by Port of Entry](https://www.archives.gov/research/immigration/ports)
- [Italian American Periodicals at the Library of Congress](https://guides.loc.gov/italian-american-periodicals/cultural-periodicals/newyork)
- The Ancestor Hunt: [Historical Italian American Newspapers Online](https://theancestorhunt.com/blog/historical-italian-american-newspapers-online/)
- [Historical Italian American Newspapers Online](https://blog.genealogybank.com/historical-italian-american-newspapers-online.html) by Thomas Jay Kemp from the Genealogy Bank blog
- New York City Newspapers at The New York Public Library: Non-English Language][9](https://libguides.nypl.org/c.php?g=1107215&p=8072759#s-lg-box-wrapper-33053697)
- [Member directory: Association of Professional Genealogists](https://www.apgen.org/directory?current_page=1&sort_type=featured&asset_type=company_user&display_type=default)